# Text doesn't appear in DOM object?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, d3.js

I'm trying to create an object in javascript and append text to it. I can append text to the svg just fine but when i try to append it to a circle for example, it doesn't appear.

This is what my code looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>D3 Tutorial</title>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js">  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>

        var canvas = d3.select("body")
                    .append("svg")
                    .attr("width", 500)
                    .attr("height", 500);

        var circle = canvas.append("circle")
                        .attr("cx", 400)
                        .attr("cy", 350)
                        .attr("r", 25);

        canvas.append("text")
            .attr("fill", "red")
            .attr("y", 50)
            .text("hello");


        circle.append("text")
                .attr("fill", "red")
                .attr("y", 50)
                .text("hello");

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is how it appears:
[image: The result]

Comment: Example http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063269

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SVGs have to follow a certain structure. Appending a `text` element to a `circle` (or `rect` or similar) isn't valid so it won't be shown.

Comment: I'm follow a youtube tutorial in which the the user is appending the the text to a rectangle, it seems to work for him, but it doesn't work for mine. src: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2S1AbEWX85o

Comment: scratch that, I was doing selectAll("rect") instead of selectAll("text"), you're right